# PCI - PA DSS - QIR

Tags: compliance, payment-gateway

I have a PA-DSS Certified program.
Do I need to be QIR Certified to remain PA-DSS Compliant?

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/program_training_and_qualification/qualified_integrator_and_reseller_certification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PA-DSS documentation](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PA-DSS_v3-2.pdf?agreement=true&time=1470170673534):

> **Integrators and Resellers**
>
> Application vendors may engage integrators and resellers to sell, install, and/or maintain payment applications on their behalf. Integrator/resellers
>   have a role to play in ensuring the secure installation and operation of payment applications, as they often provide onsite services to the vendor’s
>   customers and assist with the installation of validated PA-DSS payment applications. Incorrect configuration, maintenance or support of an
>   application may lead to the introduction of security vulnerabilities into the customer’s cardholder data environment, which could then be exploited
>   by attackers. Application vendors should educate their customers, integrators, and resellers on how to install and configure the payment
>   applications in a PCI DSS compliant manner.
>
> PCI Qualified Integrators and Resellers (QIRs) are trained by the Council in PCI DSS and PA-DSS in order to securely implement payment
>   applications. For more information on the PCI QIR program, please see www.pcisecuritystandards.org.

There's also the [QIR documentation](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/QIR_Program_Guide.pdf?agreement=true&time=1470170913143) which says:

> The goal of the QIR Program is to educate, qualify and train organizations involved in the implementation,
>   configuration and/or support of a PA-DSS validated payment application on behalf of a merchant or
>   service provider.

In other words, it *looks like* QIR is just a training course to help ensure you're using your solution in an appropriate manner, and for certifying that you're trained to PCI Council standards.  It doesn't affect the validity of the program's certification, though.